# ページ遷移数集計

Tags: sql

あるページ **"A"** から、特定のページ **"B"**、**"C"**、**"D"** に遷移した数を月次で、
かつデバイスごとに集計するにはどのようなクエリを書けばよろしいでしょうか？

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
CREATE TABLE wab_log(
  td_url text,
  td_referrer text,
  td_os text,
)
```

Comment: テーブル定義が無いと答えられないと思います。

Comment: log_webテーブルにtd_url、td_referrer、td_osがあり、
これを組み合わせて集計するようなのですが、
難しいでしょうか？？

Comment: 質問にCREATE TABLE文を張り付けてもらえれば正確かと。質問は編集することができます。

Comment: 一度編集してみましたが、いかがでしょうか？？
不足がありましたら、ご指摘いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

カラムの説明がないので推測で回答します。
直前のページが`td_referrer`に保存されている時、
「あるページ "A" から」ということなので、直前のページが"A"である。
`WHERE td_referrer='A'`

ページごと、且つ、デバイスごとにグループします。
アクセスページが`td_url`、デバイスが`td_os`、とした時、
`GROUP BY td_url, td_os;`

最後にまとめます。（テーブル名は指定がなかったので適当）

```
SELECT td_url, td_os, COUNT(*) AS td_num 
FROM test
WHERE td_referrer='A' 
GROUP BY td_url, td_os;
```

Comment: 参考になりました！ありがとうございます。